# stackNavigator inside of drawerNavigator's contentComponent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building an app with drawer-navigator. There should be custom side-menu screen which I made by contentComponent, but the problem is I need to make a navigation inside a drawer when the user pressed a button. I tried to pass stackNavigator to customComponent, this returns me "There is no route defined for key ...".

Please, could you help me, make a navigation inside the drawer without closing it.

```
const tempSN = createStackNavigator(
  {
    screen: DrawerScreen,
    screen2: ProfileSetupScreen
  },
  { initialRouteName: "screen" }
);

const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MainStack: MainStack
  },
  {
    contentComponent: tempSN, // If I pass here DrawerScreen directly, it works
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: where is mainstack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following???

```
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MainStack: MainStack
  },
  {
    contentComponent: drawerComponent,//Your drawer component.Not stack navigator.
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);

const drawerStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    drawerNav: DrawerStack,// Here is the drawer included.
    screen: DrawerScreen,
    screen2: ProfileSetupScreen
  },
);
```

Add the drawer navigation inside the stack navigation. And when you want to navigate to screen 'screen2', use like `this.props.navigation.navigate("screen2")`

Comment: What is `drawerComponent`?

Comment: @Krever the custom component used for drawer menu. Hope you understand.